# How to addExcludeRefinement on disjunctive facet?

Tags: algolia

I'm trying to add an addExcludeRefinement(facet, value) on a disjunctive facet key, but the implementation doesn't allow that.

```
if (!this.isConjunctiveFacet(facet)) {
  throw new Error(facet + ' is not defined in the facets attribute of the helper configuration');
}
```

How can I do that without having to modify the property excludesFacets itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Negative faceting can only be use with conjunctive facets. However, you can hardcode an exclusion using the `filters` attribute in the parameters. I did a jsFiddle that demonstrate that: https://jsfiddle.net/bobylito/ef4615hk/